# Render Name and id Autocomplete material UI

Tags: reactjs

i'm working with Autocomplete MUI, i want to render name and id same time in-line but it render name only, can u guys help me, thank you so much

```
export const zoneUserId = [
  { id: 1, name: 'A' },
  { id: 2, name: 'B' },
];


  const listZoneId = {
    options: zoneUserId,
    getOptionLabel: (option: IZoneID) => option.name,
  };

 <Autocomplete
   {...listZoneId}
   id="zoneUserId"
  includeInputInList
   renderInput={params => (
   <TextField {...params} label="User ID" variant="standard" />
   )}
   />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to change the getOptionLabel. Either concatenate or try like this

`` getOptionLabel: (option: IZoneID) => `${option.id} - ${option.name}` ``